# Trying to add hard drive to VM on ESXI 8, .vmdk file not found?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

Using ESXI 8.0 update 2.

Have a VM I am trying to add a hard drive from an existing .vmdk file.  Had some issues doing this through the web UI as noted [here](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/ESXi-Discussions/ESXi-8-0-unable-to-add-hard-disk-to-VM/td-p/2935954) and we had more luck using VMWare connecting to the server.

However it's still not quite working.  When we go to add the existing .vmdk file which we are able to find and select in the data store, when we go to finish we get the following error -

[image]

Which is strange to me since we selected it, it saw it there.

One thing to note is in the Web UI when we look at the file it does not look like a hard drive despite it being a .vmdk with the symbols -

[image]

The `Siemens Licenses.vmdk` pictured above was renamed as `Siemens License-flat.vmdk` before the error.  But the current file `Siemens License-flat.vmdk` looks the same - as a file not a hard drive like the `SiemensLicense.vmdk` on the right hand side.

Any ideas what is going one?  Could it be a corrupt `.vmdk` file and how could I tell?